# vifm and gvim automatically switch

Tags: vim, vifm

To open pdf file from vifm I use: `filetype *.pdf zathura %f &`. And there is automatically focus me on zathura window. But when I open any text file using: `filetype *.c,*.h gvim --remote-tab-silent %f &` I must to press `alt-tab` or `win-2` to switch to gvim window.
 Can I focus to gvim automatically?

Comment: Normally `gvim` does this automatically. E.g. `gvim --remote-tab-silent path/to/file` should be enough (it works fine for me), it might be something else that interferes, maybe your terminal, desktop environment or window manager.

Answer (score 0):

For that, Vim has the `remote_foreground()` function. Try sending that via `--remote-expr`.

Comment: `filetype *.c,*.h gvim --servername GVIM --remote-expr "foreground() " %f &`    not give me the focus, I steel need to press Alt-tab

Comment: I think you still need the `--remote-tab-silent`, and test this first by invoking manually.

Comment: `gvim --servername GVIM --remote-expr "foreground() " --remote-tab-silent gpio.c &` does not open the file at all

Comment: I feared both aren't supported in one go. You may need to invoke `gvim --servername` twice, i.e. split the file opening and foregrounding into two calls.